# Initialize Azure instance for Graph and Management API with two Access Tokens

Tags: c#, azure, access-token, azure-fluent-api

I am trying to change a working example from internet:

```
IAzure azure = Azure.Configure()
.Authenticate(credentials)
.WithSubscription(credentials.DefaultSubscriptionId)
```

into Azure Device authentication like this:

```
AzureCredentials accessTokenCredentials =  GetAzureAccessTokenCredentials(credentials,
    AzureEndPointApi.Management,
    environment);

IAzure az = Azure.Configure().Authenticate(accessTokenCredentials)
```

This still works unless I need to call some function which use Management API and Graph API together like this:

```
private static async Task<IServicePrincipal> AddAccountToRoles(IAzure azureManagement, IAzure azureGraph, IActiveDirectoryApplication activeDirectoryApp)
{
    var role = azureGraph.AccessManagement.ServicePrincipals.Define($"{activeDirectoryApp.Name}-contributor")
        .WithExistingApplication(activeDirectoryApp)
        .WithNewRoleInSubscription(BuiltInRole.Contributor, azureGraph.SubscriptionId);

     var result = await role.CreateAsync();
     return result;
}
```

CreateAsync calls both Graph AP and Management API according to to Fiddler. So I suppose it needs two different access tokens (one for each service), isn't it?

So I changed the code into:

```
var restClient = RestClient
    .Configure()
    .WithBaseUri(AzureDelegatingHandler.GetBaseUri(environment, AzureEndPointApi.Management))
    .WithEnvironment(environment)                                        
    .WithCredentials(GetAzureAccessTokenCredentials(credentials, AzureEndPointApi.Management, environment))                    
    .WithBaseUri(AzureDelegatingHandler.GetBaseUri(environment, AzureEndPointApi.Graph))
    .WithEnvironment(environment)                    
    .WithCredentials(GetAzureAccessTokenCredentials(credentials, AzureEndPointApi.Graph, environment))                    
    .Build();


IAzure azure = Azure
    .Authenticate(restClient, credentials.TenantId)
    .WithSubscription(credentials.DefaultSubscriptionId); 


public static string GetBaseUri(AzureEnvironment environment, AzureEndPointApi azureEndPointApi)
{
    switch (azureEndPointApi)
    {
        case AzureEndPointApi.Graph:
            return environment.GraphEndpoint;
        case AzureEndPointApi.Management:
            return environment.ManagementEndpoint;           
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException(azureEndPointApi.ToString());
    }
 }
```

But this code serves incorrect access token - not based on REST API endpoint base uri.

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

AzureCredentials has constructor with two access tokens, one for each API.